# git get latest remote but not overwrite my file

Tags: git, heroku, gitignore

I have a git repo. In this repo I ignore config.json (using gitignore).
I have ~5 another repos (heroku repos used for apps).

I need to get latest version of this repo, but not overwrite .gitignore (I need config.json). 
I know first I need to `git remote add bot https://git.com/Me/bot`.
I want to merge everything from `remote bot` to my local repo, but not overwrite my `.gitignore` file.
Can someone help me?

Comment: Lazy solution: `cp .gitignore ..; git pull; cp ../.gitignore .`

Comment: ok, what others steps for get from my remote branch to locally? i'm not strong at `git`

Comment: Actually, if you commit `.gitignore`, git will happily merge it for you when you pull.

Comment: If your .gitignore isn't committed, just in the working tree, you can use [stash](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash),

Comment: i ignore `config.json` in my main repo, and not ignore in my 5 others

Comment: But if you are not ignoring `config.json` in one repo then the others will not be ignoring it either independent of your `.gitignore`. So what to you want to archive exactly?